# Cassandra List <frozen> data type

Tags: cassandra

I want to display the list of fields in the Cassandra List  data type.
If i use the command for a table: "DESC Tablename" It shows all the table structure.
Similarly i would like to know the command which will display list of fields under this List column

Comment: What type (TEXT, BIGINT, UDT, etc...) is the List of?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

I just realized that you want to see the data inside a list column which is frozen.

This isn't supported in DevCenter and cqlsh as of now.
Reason: They are serialized as single entity.

Hopefully, future versions will support it.

---------- This part is wrong.

When you see a `frozen` keyword, it means that a UDT (User defined Type) is used.
So to display the inner fields, you can use `DESCRIBE TYPE type` command.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Not necessarily, the frozen keyword is also required for nested collections (i.e. map<int, frozen<list>>).  You would also need to use it if you want to use a collection type as part of a primary key.  It's also sort of an optimization as is serializes an entire collection in one cell, so you could consider using it if you don't even plan updating values for a collection column.

Comment: Desc type udt_columnname

Answer (score 0):

I am able to see the list of fields under the List data type.

In Dbeaver if i navigate to Keyspace-->Tables-->User Types-->Double click on the List field name.